# How to change Xpriter code page to code page 27?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I'm using [print_bluetooth_thermal](https://pub.dev/packages/print_bluetooth_thermal) to connect and print.

[image: Selftest]

```
List<int> command = [27,116,27];
final result = await PrintBluetoothThermal.writeBytes(command);
```

I can change any code page with this command but when it comes to cp 27, it changes to Thai instead of Vietnamese. I try Android app on [Xprinter website](https://www.xprintertech.com/xprinter-application) to change cp to 27 and it did change to Vietnamese. How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe it helps if you [edit] your question and add one command that works (for a different language) and the one that does not work

Comment: Also: which xprinter device are you using?

Comment: It's a receipt printer model N160B, I don't know any command works, the test app work but I don't have its source code.

Comment: oh ok, sounded to me like you tried different codes as well: "I can change any code page with this command but when it comes to cp 27, it changes to Thai instead of Vietnamese". SO I was wondering if a cp higher than 27 works as well

Comment: It's kinda weird, I try 28 and it change to Vietnamese, don't really know why but I think this maybe the solution for now. Thank you sm.

Comment: okay weird :D if you like, you can answer your own question and also accept that answer. That way the question gets marked as answered and can also help others with the same issue better

Comment: Perhaps using this library [esc_pos_utils_plus 2.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_utils_plus) and adding the code page information of the printer you are using to this file [flutter_esc_pos_utils/lib/resources/capabilities.json](https://github.com/mjafartp/flutter_esc_pos_utils/blob/main/lib/resources/capabilities.json) may make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda weird, I try 28 and it change to Vietnamese, don't really know why but I think this maybe the solution for now.